# Include custom library like D3js in ESlint configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, eslint

I am trying ESLint with a D3js example. I reworked the code to fit all the settings I preset when configuring ESLint, but it cannot find D3js library. It says it is undefined, of course because it doesn't know what it is or where to find it.

I added this segment in my package.json and i don't know how to add third party library ins ESlint.

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
 }
```

Is there a way to do that, so that I don't see unnecessary warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is complaining about not finding the `D3js` global variable, you can add a `globals` section to your config like so:

```
"globals": {
    "D3js": false
}
```

You can learn more about configuring globals at: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals